# Using Django filters inside model function

Tags: django, django-models

The main purpose of a model is to contain business logic, so I want most of my code inside Django model in the form of methods.  For example I want to write a method named `get_tasks_by_user()` inside task model. So that I can access it as

```
Tasks.get_tasks_by_user(user_id)
```

Following is my model code:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    slug=models.URLField()
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objects=SearchManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    days_passed = property(getDaysPassed)
    def get_tasks_by_user(self,userid):
        return self.filters(user_id=userid)
```

But this doesn't seems to work, I have used it in view as:

```
    tasks = Tasks.objects.get_tasks_by_user(user_id)
```

But it gives following error:

```
'SearchManager' object has no attribute 'get_tasks_by_user'
```

If I remove `objects=SearchManager`, then just name of manager in error will change so I think that is not issue. Seems like I am doing some very basic level mistake, how can I do what I am trying to do? I know I can do same thing via :`Tasks.objects.filters(user_id=userid)` but I want to keep all such logic in model. What is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to do this is by using [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator to make it a class method. Inside `class Tasks`:

```
@classmethod
def get_tasks_by_user(cls, userid):
    return cls.objects.filters(user_id=userid)
```

This way you can simply call:

```
tasks = Tasks.get_tasks_by_user(user_id)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use managers per Tom's answer.

To decided on which one to choose in your specific case, you can refer James Bennett's (the release manager of Django)  [blog post on when to use managers/classmethod.](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/feb/25/managers/)

Comment: A `classmethod` is a `class method` and not a `static method` which is completely different in python

Answer (score 4):

Any methods on a model class will only be available to instances of that model, i.e. individual objects.

For your `get_tasks_by_user` function to be available as you want it (on the collection), it needs to be implemented on the [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def get_tasks_by_user(self, user_id):
        return super(TaskManager, self).get_query_set().filter(user=user_id)

class Task(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = TaskManager()
```